# Rationale behind C++ integral promotion signed/unsigned rules?

Tags: c++, standards

I'm curious why the C++ Standard dictates that integral promotions prefer signed types over unsigned types, even when both values are of an unsigned type.

Example for clarity:

```
    unsigned char ch = 1;
    unsigned short s = 2;
    auto a = ch + s;
```

Naturally, `a` will be a (signed) `int` with a value of 3, as per standard [promotion behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion). No surprises there.

But I've always wondered, why not `unsigned int`?  If a type is specified as unsigned, that suggests there was (presumably) a conscious decision to do so, and so preserving unsignness in this case would seem more logical to me. Is it just to maintain consistency with the fact that types always default to signed in other contexts when signness is unspecifed? Or is there some more nuanced or interesting reasoning behind it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604299/why-do-unsigned-small-integers-promote-to-signed-int?rq=1

Comment: `Naturally, a will be a (signed) int` Well, it will be - but it's not _guaranteed_. It is _possible_ that `UCHAR_MAX == UINT_MAX` or `USHRT_MAX == UINT_MAX`, then it will be promoted to `unsigned int`. Technically, it can be an `int` or `unsigned int`.